# Create an object by receiving a 2d coordinates array

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

Hi my issue is the following, im receiving a 2d matrix and I already create a class named City, which will holds the position coordinate for x and y the values will come separated by commas like this

```
0,0
0,20
4,3
6,2
7,21

for (int k = 0; k < size; k++){                             
String valuesStrArr2[] = s.nextLine().split(",");       
for (int l = 0; l < 2; l++){                            
    int coord = Integer.parseInt(valuesStrArr2[l]);     
    System.out.println("cordinatesss:" + coord);        
    City city = new City(coord,coord);                  
    TourManager.addCity(city);                          
    }                                                       
}
```

so "coord" is the value of the array, and when i print it, has the right values but when i create the the city it duplicates the values, how can i solve this? i know is a dumb question but im stucked here.

My constructor

```
// Constructs a city at chosen x, y location
public City(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

Comment: Why does your City constructor accept two arguments that are identical? This doesn't really make sense: new City(coord,coord)

Comment: Not identical, one is for x and one for y 

    // Constructs a city at chosen x, y location
    public City(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Glen hit it on the nail. Within your second **for** loop you fill the **coord** integer variable on the first (of 2) iteration and then supply that value to both **x** and **y** of **City** in the very same iteration. You do the same thing within the second iteration. You're actually supplying twice as many Cities than you should by doing this.

Since your 2D Array has so few columns, you really don't need the inner **for** loop. You can do the whole thing with one loop and it will most likely be more readable:

```
for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
    String valuesStrArr2[] = s.nextLine().split(",");
    int coord1 = Integer.parseInt(valuesStrArr2[0]); 
    int coord2 = Integer.parseInt(valuesStrArr2[1]); 
    City city = new City(coord1, coord2);
    TourManager.addCity(city);
}
```

Comment: Whoops...Glen beat me too it :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be under the impression that `coord` will have two distinct values at the same point in time when you call `new City(coord,coord)`. The variable will only have one value at that point which will be `Integer.parseInt(valuesStrArr2[l])` This is causing you to have duplicate cities, one with the correct x coordinate and one with the correct y coordinate.

To fix this, try something like this:
**NOTE: This code will not work for you because I have not accounted for coordinate values above 9 (this code only works if all values are 1 digit values) Showing you this is intended to help you find the answer yourself**

```
String coordinates = "0, 0, 0, 20, 4, 3, 6, 2, 7, 21";

for (int k = 0; k < size; k += 2){ //This is to get every other value from the coordinates
        int x = Integer.parseInt(coordinates.charAt(k));
        int y = Integer.parseInt(coordinates.charAt(k+1));
        System.out.println("cordinatesss:" + x + ", " + y);
        City city = new City(x, y);
        TourManager.addCity(city);                                                    
}
```